# Python pandas.DataFrame.from_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The task is a very simple data analysis, where I download a report using an api and it comes as a csv file. I have been trying to convert it correctly to a DataFrame using the following code:

```
@staticmethod
    def convert_csv_to_data_frame(csv_buffer_file):
        data = StringIO(csv_buffer_file)
        dataframe = DataFrame.from_csv(path=data, index_col=0)
        return dataframe
```

However, since the csv don't have indexes inside it, the first column of the data I need is beeing ignored by the dataframe because it is considered the index column.
I wanted to know if there is a way to make the dataframe insert an index column automatically.

Comment: Have you tried `dataframe = DataFrame.from_csv(path=data, index_col=None)`?

Comment: Yes, the default is 0.

Comment: That's not the same as `None` try removing the param, at the moment you are telling pandas that the first column is an index but you're stating that none of your csvs have such a column

Comment: you were correct, works like a charm, thank you very much.how do i mark your answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error here was to assume that param `index_col=0` meant that it would not treat your csv as having an index column. This should've been `index_col=None` and in fact this is the default value so you could have not specified this and it would have worked:

```
@staticmethod
    def convert_csv_to_data_frame(csv_buffer_file):
        data = StringIO(csv_buffer_file)
        dataframe = DataFrame.from_csv(path=data) # remove index_col param
        return dataframe
```

For more info consult the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html#pandas.io.parsers.read_csv)